# Cross sections for disk or washers when rotating about the $y$-axis

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble with this cross-sections question, simply because I am not sure what to do with the function. Am I supposed to change it so it's in terms of $x$ and then graph it, or leave it how it is? What would the function look like if I made it in terms of $x$? After that I am guessing that I just using $\pi(R(x))^2$ (as in the area of a circle) for the bounds for the integration. I am just sort of unclear how to solve it.

**Problem:** Using disks or washers, find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating 
    the region bounded by the curves $x=y−y^2$ and $x=0$ about the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each horizontal line segment in the region generates a circular disc with radius $R=x=y-y^2$,

so the volume will be given by $\displaystyle V=\int_0^1\pi(y-y^2)^2\;dy=\pi\int_0^1(y^2-2y^3+y^4) \;dy$.